# Load XDocument into HTML unsorted list

Tags: c#, html, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to load a `Unsorted List` from `XML file`.

The parents tags must be loaded into `ul` and children tags into `ol`.

The problem is, i can't get the parent alone, it always print the parent value and its children.

---

XML file:

```
<Sections>
  <Section id="D2F4CD35-FB7A-4E24-9CC3-7C2095D1A2D5">
    <![CDATA[ <PARENT 1> ]]>
    <SubSection>
      <![CDATA[ <CHILED 1.1> ]]>
    </SubSection>
    <SubSection>
      <![CDATA[ <CHILED 1.2> ]]>
    </SubSection>
  </Section>

  <Section  id="CF7F2212-A4DB-47AA-8129-61AF2F930C2C">
    <![CDATA[ <PARENT 2> ]]>
    <SubSection>
      <![CDATA[ <CHILED 2.1> ]]>
    </SubSection>
    <SubSection>
      <![CDATA[ <CHILED 2.2> ]]>
    </SubSection>
  </Section>
</Sections>
```

---

C# code:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:/SectionXmlFile.xml");
    var parents = xmlDoc.Element("Sections");
    if (parents != null) {
        foreach (var parent in parents.Descendants("Section")) {    
            <ul>@parent.Value</ul>
            foreach (var child in parent.Descendants("SubSection")) {
                <ol>@child.Value</ol>
            }
        }
    }
```

---

> Result:

```
<PARETN 1> <CHILED 1.1> <CHILED 1.2>

<CHILED 1.1>

<CHILED 1.2>

<PARETN 2> <CHILED 2.1> <CHILED 2.2>

<CHILED 2.1>

<CHILED 2.2>
```

---

> Expected result:

```
<PARETN 1>

   <CHILED 1.1>

   <CHILED 1.2>

<PARETN 2>

   <CHILED 2.1>

   <CHILED 2.2>
```

Comment: Why have you included the actual and expects results as *pictures*? It makes it impossible to reformat them to make them more readable...

Comment: @JonSkeet i will edit them right now, thanks for your note :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
<ul>@parent.Value</ul>
```

That's *closing* the `<ul>` tag, rather than including each of the child elements within it.

The reason you're getting the `CHILED` elements twice is that you're using `XElement.Value` which is finding *all* the text nodes under the parent. You only want the *immediate* child text nodes.

I suspect you may want:

```
foreach (var parent in parents.Descendants("Section")) {    
    <ul>@(parent.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value)
    foreach (var child in parent.Descendants("SubSection")) {
        <ol>@child.Value</ol>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

(At least conceptually - the razor syntax may be slightly off...)

That way of finding the first text node is admittedly rather irritating. If you could change your XML that would make it easier (e.g. make each `Section` element have a `Title` element with just the right title text, or whatever) but failing that I think you're left with something like I've outlined above.

It's also unclear why you're starting new lists rather than having list *items*, but that's a different matter...

Comment: thanks, i'll try to use the title element and list items as you suggest. and i'll see what happens.
anyway it always gives me this error. "Cannot resolve tag <XText>".

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss: Ah - that'll be a matter of Razor syntax then, as it's not meant to be a tag, but a generic type argument... have edited my answer on the basis of another Stack Overflow answer...